# Return an array of objects with fieldName in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am new to springboot. My requirement is as below.
I have carModel class as below.

```
@Data
public class CarModel {
 private modelName;
 private available;
}
```

Now I have a rest endpoint that returns the list of objects. So the resource looked something like this.

```
@GetMapping("/models")
public List<CarModel> getModels(){ 
//Resource Body
}
```

But this return an array of objects in json, with no field name. But I need the the json , something like this:

```
{ "AllModels" : [ { "modelName" : "Ferrari", "available" : "Yes"} , {"modelName": "Tesla" , "available" : "Yes"} ]
```

How can I do this in spring boot? I do know of a solution by defining one more wrapper class with list of CarModel objects in it. But is there any better way of doing it(Something like any annotations, etc.,)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just missing the `AllModels` wrapper? You should be getting the array of objects with the field names by default.

Comment: He wants to avoid using a wrapper class and asks if a better alternative exist

Comment: may be create a hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ResponseEntity method that is already there available in Spring MVC. Would something like this work for you?

```
@GetMapping("/models")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CarModel>> getCars() {
        List<CarModel> carModels = service.methodThatReturnsListOfCarModels();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new HashMap<>(){{put("AllModels", carModels);}});
    }
```

Comment: "AllModels" key will not be available then

Comment: @Panagiwths Mpougioukos Well, then I guess you can create a hashmap within that. I have updated the code in soultion accordingly

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, to modify response body on the go!